# How to convert an HTML local storage service to an indexedDB service in Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, local-storage, indexeddb

I have an angular2 service that employs [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the relevant data for my application.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 

export class LocalStorageService {

  get(item) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(item));
  }

  set(target, item) {
    localStorage.setItem(target, JSON.stringify(item));
  }

  remove(item) {
    localStorage.removeItem(item);
  }
}
```

As the data grew for the application(over 15 MB now), I decided to use [IndexedDB v1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) instead of LocalStorage. Can somebody help me redefine my get(), set() and remove() functions, keeping in mind that I want the methods to be synchronous,(especially, the get() and remove() methods)?

Answer (score 0):

indexedDB methods are asynchronous. I recommend against fighting a losing battle.